# Unable to download Excel file in iOS

Tags: c#, ios, excel, web

How can you trigger a download in ASP.NET (C#) of an Excel document on an iOS device. All other devices just download the export right now. But iOS keeps giving the following response:

[image: Screenshot of iOS]

Right now I'm using the following code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ExportList(string ds)
    {
        //Generating the Excel file
        ...

        //return the file
        var fileName = Config.GetFileName("xlsx");
        return File(tempFile, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName), fileName);
    }
```

Comment: It appears it is already 'downloading' it, it just seems to be unable to read the format and display it.

Comment: There should be a way to use this feature in iOS though?

Comment: Not sure if iOS devices can read xlsx files natively. I think you'd need to download an app for that.

Comment: What type of document is it? Does the device has installed an app capable of handling the file type? are the mime types correctly configured?

Comment: @Gusman: Mimetypes are correctly configured. I actually do not have an app installed to open Excel-files. But even without an app installed I want at least a clear message (meaning: languagedependent, branded, ...). Is that possible then?

Comment: Nope, iOS relies on installed apps which have registered mime types for download/open files on the device, if the device does not have an app to handle the data type, that error you see is what you will get.

Comment: You could check if it is an iOS device, but that could be unreliable. If one were to fool your server that is an iOS device. And when you detect it you could display a message that it cannot be opened on an iOS device and under that a link with download anyway. There's no way to make it download automatically only when it has an available app that can display it

Comment: @KevinRestiaens I think you also stomped with an iOS 9 bug, take a look at this: https://origin-discussions-us.apple.com/thread/7245435

Comment: @Gusman Thanks for the information!